# How to auto convert indentation to space in monaco-editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

monaco-editor version: 0.19.0

When I copy some code and paste it to monaco-editor，it's unclear if the indentation uses spaces or tabs.

1. Is there a way to show whitespace characters?
2. Can I auto-format the editor to use replace indents with spaces?

Comment: I find the solution [How to auto convert indentation to space](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1932)